# How to replace a string after a specific characters

Tags: java

I have a string like

```
s = "x = 123 & y = abc & dateFrom >= 1234500000 & dateTo <= 654870000"
```

, which  *1234500000* and *654870000* are timestamps, I want to replace them with date like yyyy-mm-dd, I know how to convert them. My question is how can i replace them in java. knowing that the timestamps are not fix

Comment: I am using java 7

Comment: `s.replace("1234500000", dateFrom ).replace("654870000", dateTo);`??

Comment: The timestamps are not fix, they can have various value depending the case

Comment: That are very important informations. You should add this to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching:

```
    String s = "x = 123 & y = abc & dateFrom >= 1234500000 & dateTo <= 654870000";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("dateFrom >= (\\d+) &");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
            s = s.replace(m.group(1), "ABC"); //replace timestamp from

    p = Pattern.compile("dateTo <= (\\d+)");
    m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
        s = s.replace(m.group(1), "DEF"); //replace timestamp to

    System.out.println(s);
```

OUTPUT:

```
x = 123 & y = abc & dateFrom >= ABC & dateTo <= DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can extract longs with a `Pattern`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while(matcher.find()) {
  ...
}
```

In order to not consider `123` as a date, consider using some min & max values or start trying to find dates only after `dateFrom`.

Then, you can for example, parse all the `long`, convert them to dates and feed a `Map` which contains the String representation of the `long` as a key and the text representation of the date as a value.

When this is done, you can iterate on the map and call `String.replaceAll(key, value)` for each entry in the map :

```
String s = "x = 123 & y = abc & dateFrom >= 1234500000 & dateTo <= 654870000";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
long min = 200;

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
while(matcher.find()) {
  String longStr = matcher.group();
  long l = Long.valueOf(longStr);
  if(l > min) {
    String dateStr = sdf.format(new Date(l));
    map.put(longStr, dateStr);
    System.out.println("Replace " + longStr + " with " + dateStr);
  }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  s = s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

System.out.println(s);
```

Warning : You will not be able to parse dates before `01-01-1970` (timestamp = 0).